# How to execute another python file and then close the existing one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, python-os

I am working on a program that requires to call another python script and truncate the execution of the current file. I tried doing the same using the os.close() function. As follows:

```
def call_otherfile(self):
    os.system("python file2.py") #Execute new script 
    os.close() #close Current Script
```

Using the above code I am able to open the second file but am unable to close the current one.I know I am silly mistake but unable to figure out what's it.

Comment: What OS is this running on?

Comment: For now on MAC but I need a generic solution .

Comment: `os.system()` is not going to finish until the second script finishes.  You want `os.execv()` (or one of its variants) to replace the current script with the execution of the second.

Comment: could you please refer to some detailed doc or at-least some examples for that ..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this you will need to spawn a subprocess directly. This can either be done with a more low-level fork and exec model, as is traditional in Unix, or with a higher-level API like [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess).

```
import subprocess
import sys

def spawn_program_and_die(program, exit_code=0):
    """
    Start an external program and exit the script 
    with the specified return code.

    Takes the parameter program, which is a list 
    that corresponds to the argv of your command.
    """
    # Start the external program
    subprocess.Popen(program)
    # We have started the program, and can suspend this interpreter
    sys.exit(exit_code)

spawn_program_and_die(['python', 'path/to/my/script.py'])

# Or, as in OP's example
spawn_program_and_die(['python', 'file2.py'])
```

Also, just a note on your original code. `os.close` corresponds to the Unix syscall `close`, which tells the kernel that your program that you no longer need a file descriptor. It is not supposed to be used to exit the program.

If you don't want to define your own function, you could always just call `subprocess.Popen` directly like `Popen(['python', 'file2.py'])`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v8function_handler.pyx", line 48, in cefpython_py27.V8FunctionHandler_Execute
  File "file1.py", line 62, in call_otherfile
    subprocess.Popen("python file2.py")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: got the above error on using subprocess.Popen() however same works fine with os.system().

Comment: Try it with `['python', 'file2.py']`. `os.system` takes the entire command you would run in shell. `subprocess` takes the full argv as a list. `Popen('python file2.py')` is looking for a program on your path named `python file2.py`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module which is the suggested way to do that kind of stuff (execute new script, process), in particular look at [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for starting a new process and to terminate the current program you can use [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple use os.startfile and after that use exit() or sys.exit() it will work 100%
`#file 1 os.startfile("file2.py") exit()`