# Python Closing a Program After Closing Python

Tags: python

I am very new at Python so I am struggling a bit, I am creating a small program that will open an application after I input a letter linked to that application. However I have a specific problem with this piece of code.

```
if app == "M":
    subprocess.call('C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher//MinecraftLauncher.exe')
```

It will open the Minecraft launcher fine, however, Python will not say the process is complete, and so Python will not close. And if I close python manually it will close the Minecraft launcher. I am curious if there is a way to make the process open the launcher and straight away close itself so it doesn't run in the background. Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870272/how-to-execute-another-python-file-and-then-close-the-existing-one) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It fixed my issue. :) Would you mind explaining the difference between the two?

Comment: The class `Popen` when instantiated starts a process and inmediatly returns. 

The `call` function uses `Popen` to start a process, wait for it to end and then return the return code.